# Change from double to String

Tags: java, string, double

I created a calculator and it works fine. I just need that when an amount is lower than the other so it will give the message *"Amount A is less than amount B"* instead of the calculation itself.
How can I make it return my message?

Here is my code for the calculation:

```
public class CalculatorModel 
{   // Holds the value of the sum of the numbers
    // entered in the view
    private double calculationValue;

    public void calculateDiscount(double number, double number1,
        double number2, double number3, double number4,
        double number5)
    {
        if (number2 == number4 && number3 > number5);
        {
            //calculationValue = (((number2 / number3) * ((number1)) / number - 1) * 100);
        }
    }

    public double getCalculationValue()
    {
        return calculationValue;
    }     
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're familiar with `if` condition. Why not using it again?

Comment: Hi Maroun, yes I'm familiar with it, but I don't know how to make it accept that the calculationValue = ("number3 is less than number5");
it's telling me always can't convert from double to a string.
I don't want to do a lot of changes to my code, I just want to make calculationValue  = the message I want, How can this be done in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? Assuming that you have `double A` and `double B` passed from somwhere.

```
 if(A<B){
    String message = "Amount "+A+" is less than amount "+B;
    return message
 }
```

Comment: Why do you create a String variable if you return it on the next line? Just write `return "Amount [...]"` instead.

Comment: Because I find it more readable this way and this is an educational example which should in my opinion be as explicit as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to throw an `Exception` and catch the exception where you would expect to get the calculation value and display the exception message. For example:

```
throw new Exception("Amount A is less than amount B");
```

Obviously format it so that A and B are your actual values.

Answer (score 0):

Observations:

1. Your question has nothing to do with `double` to `String` conversion, which can be done by `Double.toString(d)` or simply concatenating the double with a String e.g. `"The number " + A + " is a double".`
2. throwing an `Exception` is overkill, IMHO, no point in catching that Exception to do something with it, other than printing it out.
3. You probably want the user to re-enter numbers A, and B. Thus you should not terminate the execution.
4. You could use `System.err.println("Amount A is less than amount B")` in a `while` loop, so that user re-enters A and B, until the criterion A > B is fulfilled.
5. If your program has a graphical user interface (GUI), rather than command-line interface (CLI), then you need to pop a `JDialog`, to notify the user. THere are multiple examples on [Java Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).